# How to disable file deletion confirmation in NvimTree?

Tags: linux, editor, neovim

I just installed NvimTree plugin to my neovim setup and i get annoyed by the y/n prompt when i am deleting a file. How to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Nvim's user-specific configuration file is located at
`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim`, by default `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`
add the following line to your configuration file:

```
let g:NERDTreeConfirmDelete = 0
```